# Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'int *' is disallowed with ARC after move property to .h file

Tags: objective-c, types, compiler-errors, declared-property

I have a controller which has properties defined like this in `.m` file:

```
@interface ContentViewController ()<SwipeViewDataSource, SwipeViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong)  SwipeView *swipeView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CateItem *cateItem;
@end
```

Then because I want to access `swaipView` and `cateItem` in other controller so I think it's ok to move them to the `.h` file like this:

```
@interface ContentViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong)  SwipeView *swipeView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CateItem *cateItem;
@end
```

But after doing that, previously working code like this:

```
   if([[CateItem allObjects] count ] != 0){
        self.cateItem = [CateItem allObjects][0];
    }
```

will complain like this:

[image]

What happened and how to fix this?

as required by the comment here is the `cateItem`, its a realm model

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@interface LivePhotoItem: RLMObject
@property NSString *image;
@property NSString *video;
@property NSString *fileid;
@property BOOL downloaded;
@end


RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(LivePhotoItem)
@interface CateItem: RLMObject
@property NSString *_id;
@property NSString *cateId;
@property NSString *category;
@property RLMArray<LivePhotoItem> *items;
@property NSString *cnName;
@end
```

Comment: show CateItem interface

Comment: HI, @kirander thanks for reply, have edited the question to show the `cateItem`

Comment: You have a warning on the `cateItem` property declaration too, don't you?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a forward declaration of `CateItem` to the `ContentViewController` header above the `@interface` block:

```
@class CateItem;
```

Otherwise the compiler, lacking information about the type `CateItem`, assumes type of the property to be `int *`.